Checking for understanding about integrating 1-forms and 2-forms on a complex torus
Let $S=$ {$(z,w):w^2=4z^3-z$}
$$a=\frac{(\Gamma(1/4))^2}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$$
$$t\in[0,a]$$
$$\gamma_1(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\wp(t; 1,0)$$
$$\gamma_2(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\wp(it; 1,0)$$
Let $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ be such that for all closed smooth 1-forms $\omega$ on $S$ we have:
$$\int_{\gamma_i}\omega=\int_S \omega \wedge \alpha_i$$ for $i=1,2$

Question 1
Does it follow that $$±1=\int_S \alpha_1 \wedge \alpha_2$$
since $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ intersect once?

Let $u,v\in[0,a]$
Let $\Phi:[0,a]\times[0,a]\rightarrow S$ be given by $$\Phi(u,v)=\gamma_1(t)$$ evaluated at $t=u+iv$
Question 2
After $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ have been found, will the integral $$\int_S \alpha_1 \wedge \alpha_2$$
simplify to a double integral of the form
$$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}f(u,v)\;du\;dv$$
for some suitable $f$?

Question 3
Would it be trivial or nontrivial to solve for $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$?
If it is trivial, can it be done by assuming any such $\omega$ on $S$ to be of some particular form?
If so, what would that form be?
